# How do I change my nameservers' IP addresses using SSH?

Tags: domain-name-system, ssh

How do I change my nameservers' IP addresses using SSH? I do not want to change them using cPanel.

Comment: What do you mean by "my nameservers"? Do you mean the ones this computer is using to resolve addresses? Do you mean the ones serving your domain?

Answer (score 0):

You change your nameservers via your domain name registrar, not SSH.

Comment: no , i want change name server ips in cpanel without cpanel

Comment: 1. Your question is rather unclear, then. 2. Can you explain why doing it in cPanel is unacceptable?

Answer (score 0):

If you mean the resolving name servers of that particular computer, depending on your linux distribution, check /etc/resolv.conf

Comment: root@serverAM [~]# /etc/resolv.conf
-bash: /etc/resolv.conf: Permission denied

Comment: You need to edit that file with vi, pico, emacs, or any one of another editors.  It's a configuration file.